# Github API Cannot Set User Emails

Tags: email, github, user-management

I'm trying to synchronize user names and primary emails with AD via the Github API. I make a call to /user/emails using an oAuth token with scope user:email and I get back their primary email. I then try to use PATCH /user per [this doc](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.18/v3/users/#update-the-authenticated-user) with the payload:

```
{
   email: newemail@ourcompany.com
}
```

And I get back a 404.

Is this the correct method to set the primary emails for users?

Answer (score 3):

This is due to your API request is not properly authenticated or your OAuth token does not have the required scopes. As per your question, you have set `user:email` scope which does not allow modification of the profile. Use `user` scope intead.

[image: Scopes in Githup API]

See more: [Why am I getting a 404 error on a repository that exists?](https://developer.github.com/v3/troubleshooting/#why-am-i-getting-a-404-error-on-a-repository-that-exists)

Comment: I'm calling admin/users with {"scopes": ["user:email"]} to get my OAuth token. I get the token and then call /user/emails with that token. I get back their email. I then call  /user/patch with the payload above and the same OAuth token which is when I get the 404. I tried creating another OAuth token for the Patch call but that didn't help.

Comment: @RichardSchaefer: According to the docs `"user:email"` does only [Grants **read** access to a user's email addresses.](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/#available-scopes)

Comment: @stovfl correct. I have updated the answer with your comment.

Comment: @DinushaNT: Have you proven that ***"Use `user` scope"*** will be succesfull? Because the OP uses `PATCH /user` which is bound to *"Update the authenticated user"*.

Comment: I was originally using just user but when that didn't work I tried user:email. I've not been able to get either to work.

Answer (score 1):

It requires authentication and it will return 404 Not Found, instead of 403 Forbidden, in some places. [This is to prevent the accidental leakage of private repositories to unauthorized users](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication).

You can try to make your email [`visibility`](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/emails/) to be `public`

```
[
  {
    "email": "newemail@ourcompany.com",
    "primary": true,
    "verified": true,
    "visibility": "public"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was a typo in the PATCH URL.